# Using .replacewith to change images but maintaining id. After that the image does not fire function on hover anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation, jquery-hover

When the user hovers over the image with `"id=dot0001"` a table with `id= "info0001"` that contains a checkbox with `id="checkbox0001"` becomes visible. When the user checks the box the image with `id="dot0001"` is replaced with an image that has the same id. That part works fine, the user can check and uncheck as much as he wants, the images are replaced correctly. The problem: the table does not come up when the user hovers over the image again after leaving it.

Here I define the function:

```
function makevisible(a){ 
    $("#tablespace").after(
        '<table  border="4" id="info'+a+'"class="info'+a+'">'+
        '<tr><td>Add to favorits</td><td><input name="" type="checkbox" id="checkboxinfo'+a+'" value=""></td></tr>')

        $("#info"+a).css("visibility", "hidden")

        $('#checkboxinfo'+a).change(function() {

        if($('#checkboxinfo'+a).is(':checked')){
    $('#dot'+a).replaceWith('<img src="_index/_dots/dotfavorit.gif" id="dot'+a+'" class="dot'+a+'">')
        }
else{
    $('#dot'+a).replaceWith('<img src="_index/_dots/dotnormal.gif" id="dot'+a+'" class="dot'+a+'">')  
    }   
    })

};
```

Here I use the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dot0002").hover(makevisible("0002"))
    })
```

This makes the table visible and hidden after it has been added to the html:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#dot0002").hover(
  function(){
    $("#info0002").css({"visibility":"visible"});
  },
  function(){
    $("#info0002").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
  }
);

$("#info0002").hover(
  function(){
    $(this).css({"visibility":"visible"});
  },
  function(){
    $(this).css({"visibility":"hidden"});
  }
);
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QzX9C/

I assume the problem is that jQuery does not find the image associated with the id after it has been replaced.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us an example of the problem on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I added a fiddle to make things clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you dynamically add elements to the DOM the `Hover` function dose not get attached to your new elements:

this:

```
$("#dot0002").hover(
function () {
    $("#info0002").css({"visibility": "visible"});
},
function () {
    $("#info0002").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
});
```

will not be attached to the image because it is injected dynamically to the DOM by this line of code:

```
$('#dot'+a).replaceWith('<img src="_index/_dots/dotfavorit.gif" id="dot'+a+'" class="dot'+a+'">')
```

unless you reattach it by adding a hover trigger to the .change() function

```
$('#checkboxinfo' + a).change(function () {
    if ($('#checkboxinfo' + a).is(':checked')) {
        $('#dot' + a).replaceWith('<img src="_index/_dots/dotfavorit.gif" id="dot' + a + '" class="dot' + a + '">')
    } 
    else {
        $('#dot' + a).replaceWith('<img src="_index/_dots/dotnormal.gif" id="dot' + a + '" class="dot' + a + '">')
    }

    //Add this code at the end to reattach the hover event on the newlly injected image
    $('#dot' + a).hover(
    function () {
        $("#info" + a).css({"visibility": "visible"});
    },
    function () {
        $("#info" + a).css({"visibility": "hidden"});
    });
})
```

Here is your fiddle updated: [Link...](http://jsfiddle.net/U8XtA/1/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand where exactly I should add that line.

Comment: Thanks, there was just a "o" missing after the "inf". Changed that. Now it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!